# websocket-client will not work on Python3/VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, websocket, nonetype, em-websocket-client

I am trying to use websocket-client package in Python 3.10 with VSCode on Windows 10. I am able to get the exact same code running on an Ubuntu 20.04 VM with Python 3.10.1

Here is my websocket-client version:

```
Name: websocket-client
Version: 1.2.3
Summary: WebSocket client for Python with low level API options
Home-page: https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client.git
Author: liris
Author-email: liris.pp@gmail.com
License: Apache-2.0
Location: c:\users\dazk2\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\...\websocket.py", line 32, in <module>
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:8765",
AttributeError: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'WebSocketApp'. Did you mean: 'websocket'?
```

This is the code: (This isn't what I'm working on, but sample code I tried, and it still didn't work)

```
import websocket
import _thread as thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws, a, b):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
#    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:8765",
                                 on_message = on_message,
                                 on_error = on_error,
                                 on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file name is `websocket.py`, and this is overwriting the websocket library import that is importing `websocket`. In essence, what you are doing, is importing the file to itself, and since the file itself doesn't have a `WebSocketApp` call, it crashes. Python correctly detects that it exists in the `websocket` library though (based on the crash suggestion), but since both use the same name, this causes a conflict.

If you rename your file to something different the library import should work as expected, and your coded should run.